# Save Button from Menu Bar

Tags: java, user-interface, save

Good Morning, 

 I have built a Main Form with a MenuBar, in this MainForm I put a layeredpane where I show a JInternalFrame. 
In my MenuBar I had put a JButton (Save). I would like that when I click on Save button  I can retrieve the data from the mentioned JInternalFrame.

Comment: You should Tag your question with **Java** tag instead save. It will help you to get your answer quickly.

Comment: showing the code you already have written, may help in understanding what you are (not) doing